# Using class/id to edit innerHtml in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

Hi i tried adding class and id to my innerHtml text with Javascript but after doing it, it didn't display the text it was supposed to display onclick
So I want to know how i can edit texts there without using class or id
This is my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <button id="myb">AAAAAAA</button>
        <table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><p>Monday</p></th> 
                <th><p>Tuesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Wednesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Thursday</p></th>
                <th><p>Friday</p></th>
                <th><p>Saturday</p></th>
                <th><p>Sunday</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black-mamba"><p>8:00AM</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           document.getElementById("myb").onclick = function() {
           document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML = "<table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>Jill</td><td>ggggSmith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table>";
                }
       </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A code snippet would be very helpful.

Comment: Please provide us a minimalistic example that demonstrates your issue

Comment: The problem in on line 13.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Even though sarcasm can be funny at times, we need some real clarification from OP. I'm not sure sarcasm will help.

Comment: @AndrewL64 Yeah, sure I guess but we don't want to annoy OP.

Comment: Can we also see your html? When I try your code out with my assumption of what the html would look like, it works fine.

Comment: @Yousername i've added my html code

Comment: You are making the innerHTML of a table another table... a table inside a table... You don't see that there are two tables but it's better to remove the `<table>` and `</table>` tags from your javascript.

Comment: @Kenzoid I wouldn't even characterize it as sarcasm. It's a tongue-in-cheek way of making a point. ;)

Comment: @Yousername This is a video link to what i'm trying to achieve https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NvSOXmpqieLZw9UOnX5CEMwXb_7DX9Hf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I believe you used `onclick` incorrectly.

HTML:

```html
<button id="myb" onclick="bCLick()">Some Text</button>
<table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><p>Monday</p></th> 
                <th><p>Tuesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Wednesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Thursday</p></th>
                <th><p>Friday</p></th>
                <th><p>Saturday</p></th>
                <th><p>Sunday</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black-mamba"><p>8:00AM</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("myb");
var table = document.getElementById("t01");

function bClick() { // Called when clicked
    table.innnerHTML = "<span><table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>Jill</td><td>ggggSmith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table></span>";
}
```

Although this works,  I recommend using `addEventListener` instead, its better practice:

HTML:

```html
<button id="myb" onclick="bCLick()">Some Text</button>
<table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><p>Monday</p></th> 
                <th><p>Tuesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Wednesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Thursday</p></th>
                <th><p>Friday</p></th>
                <th><p>Saturday</p></th>
                <th><p>Sunday</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black-mamba"><p>8:00AM</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("myb");
var table = document.getElementById("t01");

button.addEventListener("click", () => { // Code inside is called when t01 is clicked
    table.innerHTML = "<span><table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>Jill</td><td>ggggSmith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table></span>";
});
```

Code Snippet:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("myb");
var table = document.getElementById("t01");

button.addEventListener("click", () => { // Code inside is called when t01 is clicked
    table.innerHTML = "<span><table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>Jill</td><td>ggggSmith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table></span>";
 });
```

```html
<button id="myb">Some Text</button> <!-- No onclick -->
<table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><p>Monday</p></th> 
                <th><p>Tuesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Wednesday</p></th>
                <th><p>Thursday</p></th>
                <th><p>Friday</p></th>
                <th><p>Saturday</p></th>
                <th><p>Sunday</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black-mamba"><p>8:00AM</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
                <td><p>50</p></td>
                <td><p>Smith</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Let me add all codes to codepen and send link so you'll get me better
This is a video link to what i'm trying to achieve https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NvSOXmpqieLZw9UOnX5CEMwXb_7DX9Hf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @pj-c0d3r There's no need for Codepen. Just edit your question and add your code to a code snippet (the `<>` icon on the edit toolbar).

Comment: @pj-c0d3r I fully updated my answer to include a code snippet I recommend you check it again. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Pls you guys should be calm, I'm not sure you get what i'm saying... see what I'm trying to achieve here https://codepen.io/pj-c0d3r/pen/ExavoJb so i want another table to show after clicking the button... and i want the table to be style... how can i do that

Comment: @pj-c0d3r Check my answer m8!

Comment: What's m8 pls?? @Kenzoid

Comment: Yes @Kenzoid If i do it your way, would i be able to style the table pls?

Comment: Yeah, you would be able to.

Comment: Ok dont be annoyed pls but i'm not too good with javascript... but how can i add this to my codes? This is what i did https://codepen.io/pj-c0d3r/pen/ExavoJb

Comment: I’ll help you out when I can, as of now, I’m a bit busy. I’ll get back to you when I can.

Comment: @pj-c0d3r Ok, I'm back, let me know when you can get started.

Comment: Hi Kenz.  Can we get started now?

Comment: @pj-c0d3r, Yeah, do you have Discord? Its much easier to communicate on there rather then in the comments here.

Comment: Hey Kenz, yes I'm on discord... My username is pj c0d3r

Comment: I can't find you, add me as a friend. Username: Kenzoid#4992

Comment: Done!! I've sent you a request